# Displaying KEY values from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to display a key value from my JSON response in react. so something like this fieldData {**DMR_5_why_who_test**: "test", **why**: test}. I want to just be able to show the bolded values or key values. currently my code looks as follows. but it spits back [Object, Object] instead of my key value

```
  dotesting = () => {
    const j = Object.values(this.state.data);
    var journalEntries = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++){
        journalEntries.push(
          <div>
          <h3>{j[i].fieldData.toString()}</h3>

          </div>);

      }
      console.log(<div>{journalEntries}</div>)
     return(<div>{journalEntries}</div>);


  }
```

Comment: Use Object.keys instead

Comment: Where would i use object.keys? as part of the statement? the data is coming from an API

Comment: Instead of `Object.values`, which gives you a list of values of the object, use `Object.keys`, which gives you a list of keys on the object

Comment: Try `<h3>{Object.keys(j[i].fieldData).join(', ')}</h3>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
dotesting = () => {
    const j = Object.keys(this.state.data);
    var journalEntries = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++){
        journalEntries.push(
          <div>
          <h3>{j[i].fieldData.toString()}</h3>

          </div>);

      }
      console.log(<div>{journalEntries}</div>)
     return(<div>{journalEntries}</div>);
  }
```

Or, you can use `Object.keys(this.state.data).map()` to iterate:

```
dotesting = () => {
    const journalEntries = Object.keys(this.state.data).map(el =>
        <div>
          <h3>{el.fieldData.toString()}</h3>
        </div> 
    )
    return(<div>{journalEntries}</div>);
  }
```

Comment: why are we iterating like that though? `for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++)` -- you can use `j.forEach` or even better, `j.map` here

Comment: Sure, updtated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

to access the keys of an Object, log Object.keys() and not Oject.values

"The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own ... properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about the `fieldData` you need to use the `Object.keys` on it to extract the keys and then display those.

```
dotesting = () => {
    const j = Object.values(this.state.data);
    var journalEntries = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++){
      const keys = Object.keys(j[i].fieldData);
      journalEntries.push(
         <div>
            <h3>{keys.join(', ')}</h3>
         </div>);
    }
    console.log(<div>{journalEntries}</div>)

    return(<div>{journalEntries}</div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSX is instructing to return a div referencing journalEntries, which is an object, so it's doing what you are asking it to do.

Instead you can map over the Object's keys with Object.keys and return the value. In this manner you are telling the JSX to print each value vs the entire Array object.

Side note: I would use the Array.map static method vs a for loop as it's declarative in nature and anything declarative/functional is more idiomatic React.

```js
const someData = {
 best: 'cats',
 secondBest: 'dogs'
}

const getData = () => Object.keys(someData).map((item, index) => {
  return someData[item];
})

const App = () => (
  <div>
    {getData()}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```